# Will a stronger electromagnet magnetize/demagnetize a weaker permanent magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have this setup wherein an electromagnet and a permanent magnet are kept seperated(same poles aligned) by a small gap which is fixed irrespective of repulsion. Now considering that the permanent magnet is magnetized upto saturation and is still weaker than the electromagnet, will the permanent magnet get demagnetized and will the domains get rearranged eventually leading to attraction.

Comment: That depends on the material of the 'permanent' magnet.

Comment: Could you elaborate please. I'm thinking of using NdFeB magnets.

Comment: I don't know anything about HdFeB.  You would have to consult a manufacturer (or Google) or experiment yourself to see how resistant it is to demagnetism.  It could depend on how it is manufactured and magnetized.